# Java mail IMAPFolder class cast exception when using Jetty embedded

Tags: jakarta-mail, classcastexception, embedded-jetty

I have a problem which seems really strange to me! I am working with java mail api in some POJOs and servlets/jsps running on an embedded Jetty server. The problem is that after I retrieve all the folders, but when trying to cast an individual folder from Folder type to IMAPFolder type, this fails.
The strangest thing is that my JUnit tests work just fine the folder is casted and all the messages are retrieved. However, when running the application, it failed.
I just have the error message

```
500 ([Lcom.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage; cannot be cast to [Lcom.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage;)
```

The code is simple:

```
//...
for(Folder fl:mailFolders){

    try {
        if((fl.getType() & Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES) != 0){
        Folder f = fetch.connectToInbox(st, fl.getFullName());
            fetch.processAllMessages(f);
        }
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
//.. }

  public synchronized void processAllMessages(Folder fldr){

        IMAPFolder fl = (IMAPFolder) fldr ;
  }
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two copies of the JavaMail classes available to your application and they're being loaded by different class loaders, which is why you're getting the strange exception.